# Standalone vs. Desktop application

Tags: desktop-application

It may sound silly enough to ask but even after googling a lot I couldn't get any clear idea about it.

**What is difference between a standalone application and a desktop application?**

Some where I read that the application without GUI running in local context is called standalone application while a standalone application with GUI is called desktop application. But I am not convinced with it.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no difference. There is only a difference between a standalone application and a client-server application.

Comment: Yes like @UwePlonus mentioned, Standalone applications are just solitary and do not communicate and if they have a GUI as well they can be called Desktop applications which is just a fancy name.

Comment: How its related with java, c or c++ ?

Comment: @Neelu Basu: I had no idea to give a suitable tag for it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Standalone software applications** may refer to:

- Computer software that can work offline, i.e. does not necessarily require network connection to function
- Software that is not a part of some software bundle
- A program that is run as a separate computer process, not an add-on of an existing process
- Standalone program, a program that does not require operating system's services to run
- A portable application, which can be run without the need for installation procedure
- Stand-alone expansion pack, expansion packs that do not require the original game
- Standalone applications are traditional software that are installed on each client system

And, **Desktop application** is

- An application that runs stand alone in a desktop or laptop computer. Contrast with "Web-based application," which requires the Web browser to run.

So, these two words represent the same class of software systems.

More on: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standalone_software) , [EssenceComputing](http://www.essencecomputing.com/standalone_software.php), [PCmag](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/41158/desktop-application)

Answer (score 0):

Desktop applications are just Standalone applications with a GUI.